# Where/How can I get the Android SDK OEM USB Drivers for a Samsung Galaxy Player (YP-G1)

Tags: android, mobile, driver, galaxy

I've been doing some Android development but the virtual testing environment is too slow for me and oftentimes doesn't work at all. I have a Samsung Galaxy Player (Model YP-G1) and I've searched Google as well as [Samsung's driver website](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/downloads) for my device and I can't find any drivers that will allow me to test Apps I develop in Eclipse on my Galaxy Player. Samsung's site only has one driver, which is apparently something to aid in the syncing of music with the computer.

Comment: Have you enabled debug mode in settings?

Comment: Start off with this thread. http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1492188 In many cases, you can edit adb.ini manually.  Also search for naked usb driver.  It may help

Comment: Morrison - Yes, I did enable debug mode.
Simon - Sorry, what should I be looking for in that thread? It looks like it's for other Samsung Galaxy devices.

Comment: It explains how to add a device to adb.ini.  Of course, you would substitute your manufacturer and device IDs but the principal is the same.

Answer (score 23):

Even though this question is a bit outdated I stumbled upon it in my quest to find drivers for the Samsung Galaxy S4.

The Samsung development drivers can be downloaded here (notice the spelling mistake in the url but at the moment of writing this is the actual link!):
http://developer.samsung.com/android/tools-sdks/Samsung-Andorid-USB-Driver-for-Windows